# React typescript for added antdesign (antd) modal not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

Im tried to put my `React typescript` application for [Ant design Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/), but its not working correctly, anyone know how to put hat concretely on react typescript

i got a this folwling error

```
Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006

    11 |     };
    12 |
  > 13 |     handleOk = e => {
       |                ^
    14 |         console.log(e);
    15 |         this.setState({
    16 |             visible: false,
```

**My code here**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';

class Uni extends React.Component {

    state = { visible: false };

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    };

    handleOk = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    };

    handleCancel = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    };

    public render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
                    Open Modal
                </Button>
                <Modal
                    title="Basic Modal"
                    visible={this.state.visible}
                    onOk={this.handleOk}
                    onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                >
                    <p>Some contents...</p>
                    <p>Some contents...</p>
                    <p>Some contents...</p>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Uni;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is simply to give it a type, in TypeScript you cannot have implicit any types.

HandleOK = (e: any) => { ... }

And instead of any you can look up The typescript type for an event like that, not sure what the correct one is on the top of my head

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, its worked for me :)

Comment: I suggest you give actual `types` rather than `any`.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said He could look into the types of events, but the question was about how to fix the Issues, which any does. Types for events can be a bit tricky at frist, so starting with any to make the application run at all is a good starting point imho